# nodejs passport 'done()' confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, google-api

I have been following [theNetNinjas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PuMp5tQ8Jw)' youtube serie on creating an authentication page with passport. However this one video confused me a lot.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
const keys = require('./keys');
const User = require('../../../models/authDatabase');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {       //  THIS TRIGGERS SECOND <----
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {     // THIS TRIGGERS THIRD <----
    User.findById(id).then(user => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });
});

passport.use(            // THIS TRIGGERS FIRST <-------
        new GoogleStrategy({
            // options for the google strat
            clientID: keys.google.clientID,
            clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: '/projects/auth/google/redirect'
        }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            // passport callback function
            console.log('passport callback function fired');
            User.findOne({googleId: profile.id}).then(user => {
                if (user) {
                    // The user is already registered
                    console.log('user is:', user.googleId);
                    done(null, currentUser);
                } else {
                    // if not, create user in our db
                    new User({
                        username: profile.displayName,
                        googleId: profile.id
                    }).save().then(newUser => {
                        console.log('new user created:' + newUser);
                        done(null, newUser)
                    })
                }
            });
        })
);
```

I find it very weird how the `done` method know where to go next. At first I thought it was order based, so that it triggered the next function defined underneath the function it was called from, but this is clearly not the case as you can see it jumps up to the top and runs the `passport.serializeUser`, why is that?

Asked in another way: How does the `done` method know how to trigger the `passport.serializeUser` function instead of the `passport.deserializeUser` function?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is not just one `done` function. Whenever you take that as a parameter, it is passed as an argument by Passport, and depending on the usage they might pass in different things. Simplified example:

```
 function GoogleStrategy(options, callback) {
   callback(1, 2, 3, function strategyDone(error, user) {
    serializeUser(user, function serializeDone(error, id) {
      //...
    });
  });
 }
```

Comment: What is `ut`? What exactly do you mean by `there is not just one "done" function`? - that I am calling the done function multiple places throughout the file?

Comment: @ryan *that I'm calling the done function multiple places* ... no, not *the function*. *the functions* ...

Comment: I dont get it. If I asked you, how does it know where to go next when I call `done`. What would you answer? (Your answer is kinda vague in the way that it doesn't directly answer that question on 'how does it know where to go next')

Comment: @ryan it does answer the question, I guess you should read a bit more about callbacks.

Comment: Well you are nesting your callback functions, in my example the callback is not nested inside the function. So how does the call to `done` know where to go - *in my example code*?